# how to understand at which line xml is getting error in php

Tags: php, xml

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 462: Opening and ending tag mismatch: post line 0 and row1
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Now how to understand column 462 in my code?

Comment: Well, what is on column 462?

Comment: *"Now how to understand column 462 in my code?"* If you, who made it, can't understand it, what makes you think that we, who have never seen it, will make any sense of it?

Comment: I guess this error tells you where the error is in your `xml` file, not `php` file... check xml for pointer at line 1, column 462 and then find where it's generated in php. You should also post some code, cause at this stage, any help you will get will be just conjecture.

Comment: Column 462 refers to the 462nd character on line 1. Can you post the code for line 1?

Comment: <?php
include("connect.php");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category ");

 /* create one master array of the records */
 $posts = array();
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $k=0;
 $a=$post['id'];
 $result2= mysql_query("SELECT image,price,quantity FROM flower where $a = flower.id");
 $postin = array();
 if(mysql_num_rows($result2)) {
  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

  
  $postin[] = array( 'row1' => $row1);
 }}
 $posts[]=array(   //$posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
 'post' => $post
 );
 
}
 }

Comment: this is my first half code now I am giving second half of my code:

Comment: header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<Details>';
foreach($posts as $index => $post) {
if(is_array($post)) {
foreach($post as $key => $value) {
echo '<',$key,'>';
    if(is_array($value)) {
      foreach($value as $tag => $val) {
       echo '<',$tag,'>',htmlentities($val),'</',$tag,'>';
}
foreach($postin as $index => $row1) {
if(is_array($row1)) {
foreach($row1 as $key => $value) {
echo '<',$key,'>';
if(is_array($value)) {
foreach($value as $tag => $val) {
echo '<',$tag,'>',htmlentities($val),'</',$tag,'>';}}
echo '</',$key,'>';}}}}
echo '</',$key,'>';}}}
echo '</Details>';?>

Comment: @ Pekka I am nt getting where column 462  will be in my php file

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all of your code is written on one line for "micro-optimization" purposes. Unfortunately this hurts readability a tremendous amount.

**Please turn this:**

```
<?php include("connect.php"); $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category "); /* create one master array of the records */ $posts = array(); if(mysql_num_rows($result)) { while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $k=0; $a=$post['id']; $result2= mysql_query("SELECT image,price,quantity FROM flower where $a = flower.id"); $postin = array(); if(mysql_num_rows($result2)) { while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) { $postin[] = array( 'row1' => $row1); }} $posts[]=array( //$posts[] = array('post'=>$post); 'post' => $post ); } }header('Content-type: text/xml'); echo '<Details>'; foreach($posts as $index => $post) { if(is_array($post)) { foreach($post as $key => $value) { echo '<',$key,'>'; if(is_array($value)) { foreach($value as $tag => $val) { echo '<',$tag,'>',htmlentities($val),'</',$tag,'>'; } foreach($postin as $index => $row1) { if(is_array($row1)) { foreach($row1 as $key => $value) { echo '<',$key,'>'; if(is_array($value)) { foreach($value as $tag => $val) { echo '<',$tag,'>',htmlentities($val),'</',$tag,'>';}} echo '</',$key,'>';}}}} echo '</',$key,'>';}}} echo '</Details>';?>
```

**Into something that looks like this:**

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category "); /* create one master array of the records */
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    // A LOT OF CODE
}
?>
```

Make sure to create new lines and indent when necessary. Please edit your initial question if possible with new code, or create a new question.

thank you